# Read the VW raw scores from (CS)OAA

Tags: r, parsing, vowpalwabbit

VowpalWabbit writes raw predictions from (CS)OAA model as a sequence of lines like this:

```
1:-2.31425 2:-3.98557 3:-3.97967 4:-2.63708 5:-3.18749 6:-2.43984 7:-4.99018 8:-3.49138 9:-3.07816 10:-6.15126 11:-6.01152 12:-5.76039 13:-5.13096 14:-5.18472 15:-5.37358 16:-5.24147 17:-5.21512 18:-5.67961 19:-4.62929 20:-4.61404 000db8cd6aef4e5fa459126d36e0fa1f-none
1:-2.65864 2:-3.33924 3:-2.8116 4:-1.83108 5:-2.05677 6:-1.29879 7:-6.7446 8:-3.05036 9:-2.82138 10:-5.19605 11:-4.5119 12:-5.28309 13:-4.35789 14:-4.76992 15:-4.16866 16:-4.6897 17:-3.76224 18:-4.13129 19:-4.4489 20:-4.32605 000e0e58a4cb4a218bbc6cae0b1af201-none
```

### How do I read it into `R`?

Here is my code:

```
## load raw vw (CS)OAA scores
read.vw.oaa.scores <- function (myfile) {
  v <- sapply(strsplit(readLines(myfile),' ',fixed=TRUE), function (r) {
    m <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(head(r,-1),':',fixed=TRUE)),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
    stopifnot(identical(1:nrow(m),as.integer(m[,1])))
    c(tail(r,1),m[,2])
  })
  f <- as.data.frame(t(v),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names(f) <- c("id",head(names(f),-1))
  for (n in tail(names(f),-1))
    f[[n]] <- as.numeric(f[[n]])
  f
}
```

Are there any obvious bugs/inefficiencies?
Is there a better way?

PS. This data format looks like [CRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112558/read-write-data-in-libsvm-format) but it is not it.

Answer (score 0):

See if the following works for you (probably really slow). Assumes all desired values are in numeric:value format. And uses raw which requires each line to be stored as a character array.

```
raw = c("1:-2.31425 2:-3.98557 3:-3.97967 4:-2.63708 5:-3.18749 6:-2.43984 7:-4.99018 8:-3.49138 9:-3.07816 10:-6.15126 11:-6.01152 12:-5.76039 13:-5.13096 14:-5.18472 15:-5.37358 16:-5.24147 17:-5.21512 18:-5.67961 19:-4.62929 20:-4.61404 000db8cd6aef4e5fa459126d36e0fa1f-none",
"1:-2.65864 2:-3.33924 3:-2.8116 4:-1.83108 5:-2.05677 6:-1.29879 7:-6.7446 8:-3.05036 9:-2.82138 10:-5.19605 11:-4.5119 12:-5.28309 13:-4.35789 14:-4.76992 15:-4.16866 16:-4.6897 17:-3.76224 18:-4.13129 19:-4.4489 20:-4.32605 000e0e58a4cb4a218bbc6cae0b1af201-none")
```

Function to clean

```
clean = function(t, n) {as.numeric(gsub("^[0-9]+:", "", unlist(strsplit(t, split=" "))[1:n]))}
lapply(raw, clean, n = 20)

[[1]]
 [1] -2.31425 -3.98557 -3.97967 -2.63708 -3.18749 -2.43984 -4.99018 -3.49138 -3.07816 -6.15126 -6.01152 -5.76039
[13] -5.13096 -5.18472 -5.37358 -5.24147 -5.21512 -5.67961 -4.62929 -4.61404

[[2]]
 [1] -2.65864 -3.33924 -2.81160 -1.83108 -2.05677 -1.29879 -6.74460 -3.05036 -2.82138 -5.19605 -4.51190 -5.28309
[13] -4.35789 -4.76992 -4.16866 -4.68970 -3.76224 -4.13129 -4.44890 -4.32605
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that, first, your return value is not a `data.frame`. Second, you are dropping IDs. Third, you are not doing error checking (see `stopifnot` in my code).