# Optimising sapply() or for(), paste(), to efficiently transform sparse triplet matrix to a libsvm format

Tags: r, performance

I have a piece of R code I want to optimise for speed working with larger datasets.  It currently depends on `sapply` cycling through a vector of numbers (which correspond to rows of a sparse matrix).  The reproducible example below gets at the nub of the problem; it is the three line function `expensive()` that chews up the time, and its obvious why (lots of matching big vectors to eachother, and two nested `paste` statements for each cycle of the loop).  Before I give up and start struggling with doing this bit of the work in C++, is there something I'm missing?  Is there a way to vectorize the `sapply` call that will make it an order of magnitude or three faster?

```
library(microbenchmark)

# create an example object like a simple_triple_matrix
# number of rows and columns in sparse matrix:
n <- 2000 # real number is about 300,000
ncols <- 1000 # real number is about 80,000

# number of non-zero values, about 10 per row:
nonzerovalues <- n * 10

stm <- data.frame(
  i = sample(1:n, nonzerovalues, replace = TRUE),
  j = sample(1:ncols, nonzerovalues, replace = TRUE),
  v = sample(rpois(nonzerovalues, 5), replace = TRUE)
)

# It seems to save about 3% of time to have i, j and v as objects in their own right
i <- stm$i
j <- stm$j
v <- stm$v

expensive <- function(){
  sapply(1:n, function(k){
    # microbenchmarking suggests quicker to have which() rather than a vector of TRUE and FALSE:
    whichi <- which(i == k)
    paste(paste(j[whichi], v[whichi], sep = ":"), collapse = " ")
  })
}

microbenchmark(expensive())
```

The output of `expensive` is a character vector, of `n` elements, that looks like this:

```
 [1] "344:5 309:3 880:7 539:6 338:1 898:5 40:1"                                                                                
 [2] "307:3 945:2 949:1 130:4 779:5 173:4 974:7 566:8 337:5 630:6 567:5 750:5 426:5 672:3 248:6 300:7"                         
 [3] "407:5 649:8 507:5 629:5 37:3 601:5 992:3 377:8"
```

For what its worth, the motivation is to efficiently write data from a sparse matrix format - either from `slam` or `Matrix`, but starting with `slam` - into libsvm format (which is the format above, but with each row beginning with a number representing a target variable for a support vector machine - omitted in this example as it's not part of the speed problem).  Trying to improve on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112558/read-write-data-in-libsvm-format/15031569#15031569). I forked one of the repositories referred to from there and adapted its approach to work with sparse matrices with [these functions](https://github.com/ellisp/r-libsvm-format-read-write/blob/master/R/write-sparse-triplets-svm.R).  The [tests](https://github.com/ellisp/r-libsvm-format-read-write/blob/master/tests/test-dense-sparse.R) show that it works fine; but it [doesn't scale up](https://github.com/ellisp/r-libsvm-format-read-write/blob/master/example/size-limits-sparse-to-h2o.R).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use package data.table. Its `by` combined with the fast sorting saves you from finding the indices of equal `i` values.

```
res1 <- expensive()


library(data.table)
cheaper <- function() {
  setDT(stm)
  res <- stm[, .(i, jv = paste(j, v, sep = ":"))
      ][, .(res = paste(jv, collapse = " ")), keyby = i][["res"]]

  setDF(stm) #clean-up which might not be necessary
  res
}

res2 <- cheaper()

all.equal(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark(expensive(),
               cheaper())  
#Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
# expensive() 127.63343 135.33921 152.98288 136.13957 138.87969 222.36417   100   b
#   cheaper()  15.31835  15.66584  16.16267  15.98363  16.33637  18.35359   100  a
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks.  Now the full operation, including writing to disk, of a 300,000 by 83,000 sparse matrix takes just two minutes.

Comment: Note that data.table is now parallelized internally. `fwrite` might also be of interest.